# Would the following series of implications be logically correct?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers, and let $f$ be a generic function satisfying $f(1) = 1$, and taking on only positive integer values.

Suppose that I have the following propositions:

$$\bf{A} : a < b$$
$$\bf{B} : f(a) < f(b)$$
$$\bf{C} : \dfrac{f(a)}{a} < \dfrac{f(b)}{b}$$
$$\bf{D} : \dfrac{f(a)}{b} < \dfrac{f(b)}{a}$$

For our purposes, assume that we know that **Proposition C** is true.  Assume that we also know that for all possible $a$ and $b$, $a \neq b$ and $\dfrac{f(a)}{b} \neq \dfrac{f(b)}{a}$.

Would the following series of implications be logically correct?

> $$\bf{A} \implies \bf{B} \implies \bf{D}$$

**My Attempt**

Assume that **Proposition A** is true.  Then $a < b$.

Rearranging **Proposition C**:
$$\dfrac{f(a)}{f(b)} < \dfrac{a}{b} < 1$$
thereby getting **Proposition B**.

Now here is where I may be misunderstanding elementary logic.

I know that the following implication is true:
$$\{\bf{A} \land \bf{B}\} \implies \bf{D}$$
since **Proposition A** can be rewritten as
$$a < b \iff \dfrac{1}{b} < \dfrac{1}{a}.$$

What I'm thinking is that, if $\bf{A}$ is true, then $\bf{B}$ follows, therefore $\bf{D}$ must be true.  Consequently, the series of implications:

> $$\bf{A} \implies \bf{B} \implies \bf{D}$$

must be true.

**Questions**

> **(1)** Is there an error in elementary logic in the last paragraph above?
>
> **(2)** If the answer to **(1)** is *YES*, how can we rectify the implication to come up with a logically correct one?

Comment: Fixed.  I restrict $f$ to take on only positive values.

Comment: Everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow(0,\infty)$ and $a,b\in(0,\infty)$ be given with $a<b$. Suppose
$$
\frac{f(a)}{a}<\frac{f(b)}{b}.
$$
Then, the above yields
$$
\frac{f(a)}{f(b)}<\frac{a}{b}<1.
$$
From this it follows that $f(a)<f(b)$. Multiplying both sides of the inequality by $a$ and applying $a<b$ yields $af(a)<af(b)<bf(b)$.
Rearranging, we get the desired inequality:
$$
\frac{f(a)}{b}<\frac{f(b)}{a}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, par!  So just to clarify, the series of implications
$$a < b \implies f(a) < f(b) \implies \dfrac{f(a)}{b} < \dfrac{f(b)}{a}$$
is indeed true?

Comment: Yes. Note that we did not use most of what was in the question. We do not need to know that $f(1)=1$, we do not need $f$ to be a function (we only care about $f$ valued at 2 points). There was some other stuff too that was extraneous.

Comment: Okay thanks!  I took the liberty of changing your last inequality
$$\dfrac{f(a)}{b} < \dfrac{f(a)}{a}$$
to
$$\dfrac{f(a)}{b} < \dfrac{f(b)}{a}.$$
I hope you don't mind.  =)